# How can I give a web user the ability to control my code using code?

Tags: javascript

I made an interesting little gadget using `p5.js`, which I would like to share on my web page. I am not a web developer and the gadget is just a static web page that displays some graphics, really nothing fancy.

Currently, to use the gadget, you have to write a little Javascript function that gets called inside the gadget's main loop, which in turn calls various functions that affect the gadget's behaviour. For this reason, I want to make a static web page in which the user can enter code to control the gadget. For this I seem to have three main options:

1. Simply allow the user to enter Javascript in the text box, and use `new Function()` to run it.
2. Allow the user to enter Javascript, but sandbox it, using one technique or another.
3. Allow the user to write code in some other language, then parse and interpret it within my code.

My first question is, **is option 1 safe**, given that this is a static web page and everything is running in the browser? There are many previous questions that ask essentially this, but they are mostly very old, and the answers seem to be pretty evenly split between "no it's not safe" and "it's fine as long as it's on the user's local machine". If this can be done safely in 2018 then my problem is solved and I will be happy.

If option 1 is not advisable, my second question is, **is there an easy way to achieve option 2?** There are several libraries available for sandboxing Javascript code, but they all seem to have much more heavyweight purposes than my simple case of running user code on a static page. Some answers to previous similar questions say one should run the user code in an iframe, but as a web/Javascript novice I am unsure what this really means, or how to achieve it. Can sandboxing user code be done simply, or would I have to learn one of these heavyweight libraries?

If options 1 and 2 fail, my third question is, **what existing solutions exist for option 3?** The user code doesn't need to do anything complicated at all, just assign things to variables, call basic math functions, and call some Javascript functions that are implemented in my script. In principle it would not be hard to design and implement a mini-language with these features, but that becomes a whole new project. Is there an existing language with a Javascript interpreter that's designed for this kind of purpose?

Comment: Does the user's Javascript ever go anywhere other than on their own machine? If not, option 1 should be safe. If it were transferred to a server or something like that where *other* users might stumble across it, *that* might be a problem (though, how much of one, I'm not sure - eg think of JSFiddle vs a banking website)

Comment: @CertainPerformance the gadget doesn't do anything that interacts with another machine, and I am not planning to have any feature where the code can be saved or transferred anywhere. Users might share code with each other on web forums etc. though.

Comment: @Nathaniel if *"the code cannot be saved"* than how are users supposed to share the code they created?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ctrl-C, go to web forum, ctrl-V

Comment: @Nathaniel that one was way too obvious :D